# JS Class create multiple callback functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a modal class that, among other things, would be able to catch the onClose & onSubmit events and handle them separately.

So in one side of my app I would be doing something like this:

```
new Modal().setTitle('Some title')
    .onClose(function(form, modal)
    {   
        
    })
    .onSubmit(function(form, modal)
    {

    });
```

And somewhere else I might just do:

```
new Modal().setTitle('Some title');
```

If not possible, I'm ok with not nesting the functions:

```
const modal = new Modal().setTitle('Some title');
modal.onClose = function(form, modal)
{
    
};
modal.onSubmit = function(form, modal)
{
    
};
```

With that said, my current class is the following and can be seen in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q61z907y/)**:

```
class Modal
{
    #btnClose;
    #btnConfirm;
    #modal;
    #form;

    constructor()
    {
        const self = this;

        this.#btnClose = document.getElementById('btn-close');
        this.#btnConfirm = document.getElementById('btn-confirm');
        this.#form = document.getElementById('form');    
        this.#modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modal'), {});
        this.#modal.toggle();
        this.#btnClose.onclick = function()
        {
            self.#_onClose(self);
        }
    }

    #_onClose(self)
    {
        // default behavior
        self.#modal.toggle();
        
        // should call onClose() function
        self.onClose(() => (self.#form, self.#modal));
    }


    onClose(callback)
    {
        callback(this.#form, this.#modal);
        
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Problems**:

1. The `onClose()` function is being called after pressing the «Open modal» button
2. The `onClose()` function is never called after pressing the «Close» button

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: [What is your actual _question_ though](/help/how-to-ask)? You've described what you want to do, and you've shown some code that you already wrote, so that's parts 1 and 2 covered, but where is the rest? Where's your description of what it did instead of what you expected, and where is your description of the debugging/(re)searching you already did to try to solve the problem? And on a general JS note: don't mark everything private, JS doesn't need it, your code doesn't get any better from it. Only mark things private when you actually know _why_ they should be.

Comment: As stated in the last part of my post, I mentioned the problems which I can't fix. The expected result does not happen.

Comment: Right, but reread your post, because you're not asking a question right now. You're stating problems, you're not talking about how you already tried to solve them, and then the post ends. Right now, it's a "how do I do X?" post, which isn't on-topic yet. Rewrite it to a explain why you wrote the code that you wrote (including why you're using that curious private indirection), why you expected that to work, and what part(s) you already tried to change (and why) to try and fix things. Because if you need chaining you already know how that should be done (because of what your `onClose` does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

```
class Modal
{
    #btnClose;
    #btnConfirm;
    #modal;
    #form;
    #clickedOnClose;
    #callbackOnClose;

    constructor()
    {
        const self = this;
        
        this.#btnClose = document.getElementById('btn-close');
        this.#btnConfirm = document.getElementById('btn-confirm');
        this.#form = document.getElementById('form');    
        this.#modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modal'), {});
        this.#modal.toggle();
        this.#btnClose.onclick = function()
        {
            self.#clickedOnClose = true;
            self.onClose(self.#callbackOnClose);
        }
    }

    onClose(callback)
    {       
        this.#callbackOnClose = callback;

        if (this.#clickedOnClose && this.#callbackOnClose) 
            callback(this.#form, this.#modal);
    }
}

const btnOpen = document.getElementById('btn-open');
btnOpen.onclick = function()
{
    new Modal().onClose(function(form, modal)
    {
        // works and is only called when clicked on the close button
        console.log(form);
        console.log(modal);
    });
}
```